# Как происходит расчет физики и отрисовка графики в разных потоках?

Tags: java, android, многопоточность, разработка-игр

Решил дописать игрушку: Есть 4 фигуры который двигаются по экрану. например метод `figure.update()` перерасчитывает координаты фигуры. И есть пятая фигура, которой я управляю посредством касания к сенсору.  Переопределенный метод `onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)` считывает данные с сенсора и обновляет координаты мной управляемой фигуры.  Теперь как идет отрисовка: выполнил `figure.update()` для всех фигур, нарисовал. А вот управляемая мной фигура тоже рисуется на втором шаге, но изменение ее координат происходит в зависимости от касаний сенсора. Т.е. может возникнуть ситуация , что в момент когда я рисую, обновились координаты фигуры,  X уже обновлен, а переменная Y еще не обновлена. 
В итоге отрисуется не совсем верное положение фигуры. Возможно на 60 fps эти косяки не заметны..я лично не вижу никаких таких ошибок, когда запускаю игру, как будто всё точно рассчитывается. Но ведь по логике ошибки должны быть..Разве не должна возникнуть такая ошибка: что идет отрисовка, а у этой фигуры координата в этот момент обновляется сенсором, ведь работа от сенсора идет в UI потоке, а весь остальной расчет физики и отрисовки в доп. потоке. Выходит я должен эти переменные пометить как синхронизированные, но даже без этой пометки никаких исключений нет.

Я бы привел код, но думаю он тут лишний, еще раз повторюсь: В UI потоке изменяется значение фигуры в зависимости от результатов сенсора, а в доп. потоке идет отрисовка этой фигуры. Почему нет исключений, вызванных тем, что на отрисовку нужна координата, которая в данный момент изменяется в UI потоке. Или же почему не заметно на глаз таких вот моментов, что координата X изменилась при резком движении по сенсору , а Y еще имеет старое значение. 
Мне в голову приходит такой ответ: UI потоку всего то надо от сенсора полученные две переменные обновить и справляется с этим он быстро. Доп. поток имеет всегда обе координаты считанные от одного и того же считывания сенсора. Но вопрос остается такой: если UI часто обновляется координаты (я быстро вожу пальцем по  экрану), то почему доп. поток не нарывается на ситуация, когда координата занята записью из UI потока.

Comment: Используются всякие объекты синхронизации и поочередный расчет. Как вы верно заметили, одновременно это делать **нельзя**.

Comment: Но это наверно сильно снизит производительность. Каждый раз ждать пока UI поток освободит переменную от записи и можно будет доп. потоку брать их из модели ? А ведь UI поток может очень часто занимать переменные и возможно доп. поток вообще ничего не сможет получить

Comment: К примеру, вы делаете расчет физики 50 раз в секунду (чаще не имеет смысла, т.к. на экране вы не увидите более 100кадров в сек и поймете что что-то движется не идеально). Каждый тик физики вы можете смотреть изменилось ли что-то, пришли ли новые команды от игрока, и примените их. Команды игрока обычно буферизируются.

Comment: Понимаете, есть такая проблема, что фигура которой я управляю через сенсор получает мало координат, когда я провожу быстро по сенсору. Т.е. если фигура от низа экрана переместилась к верху , сделала она это получив линию из всего 7 координат, например.  Выходит я могу проходить сквозь другие фигуры, хоть они и были на моей траектории движения.  Изменить частоту получения координат от сенсора я не могу (хотя сейчас пришла идея искусственно их добавить, поляризацию проводить, не знаю поможет ли). Пока я часто просчитываю физику чтобы шаг движения мною не управляемых фигур был маленьким.

Comment: Чем меньше их шаг, тем большее вероятность что моя фигура не сможет пройти на сквозь и коллизия произойдет. Поэтому физика у меня просчитывается столько раз сколько позволяет производительность телефона (привязку скорости от производительности я конечно же убрал, умножаю шаг на  время за которое успел пройти просчет, в игровых движках этот коэффициент называют deltaTime (в libgdx) или pSecondsElapsed (AndEngine))

Comment: Но это всё не так важно. Вы говорите каждый тик физики проверять некий буфер, куда складываются все event'ы от экрана и брать их из этого массива.  Это бы сработало от игры где на экране кнопки всякие и нажимаешь на них не часто. Но у меня очень динамичная игра, фигура должна убегать от других фигур и должно  обрабатываться как можно больше касаний к экрану и как можно ближе к реальному времени.  А в том подходе который вы предлагаете, получится что в буфере будут лежать уже не актуальные координаты,  все будет с запозданием.

Comment: 50 тиков в секунду более чем достаточно для быстрой игры. Пролет через другие тела решается на стороне обработчика коллизий (проверяйте не только точки на коллизию, но и путь между ними).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используются объекты синхронизации и поочередный расчет физики, отрисовки и ввода от пользователя. Как вы верно заметили, одновременно работать с данными из нескольких потоков просто так нельзя.

К примеру, вы делаете расчет физики 50 раз в секунду (чаще не имеет смысла, т.к. на экране вы не увидите более 100 кадров в сек и поймете что что-то движется не идеально). Каждый тик физики вы можете смотреть изменилось ли что-то, пришли ли новые команды от игрока, и примените их. Команды игрока обычно буферизируются и обрабатываются между физикой и отрисовкой. То есть ваша программа будет работать примерно так:

```
Ф О О О В Ф О О В Ф О О О В Ф О О // Ф-физика, О-отрисовка, В-ввод от игрока
```

Физика и команды обрабатываются с фиксированным шагом, отрисовка - сколько успеет. Для плавности картинки - используйте интерполяцию (или экстраполяцию).

Пролет через другие тела решается на стороне обработчика коллизий (проверяйте не только точки на коллизию, но и полный путь между ними).

Comment: для игры, где игрок нажимает на кнопки управления на экране, команды конечно надо буферизовать. А если командой игрока является движение пальцем по экрану, которое должен повторять его персонаж, не обязательно буферизовать всю траекторию. В принципе касания от экрана не столь многочисленны и их не больше 30 за секунду, поэтому я просто при каждом подсчете физики беру текущую координату от игрока.    НО это тонкости данной игры.   В общем случае предложенный вами вариант подходит. У меня есть сложности с коллизиями, но это отдельный вопрос.